# Settimeout UI refresh and heavy loops strategy

Tags: javascript, html

I have a loop of 2000 read operations over 3 tables (DB). Each one spedts almost 0.5 seconds to be completed (or less)
I want to show a text "Pass 1, Pass 2, Pass 3"
So I'm trying to use settimeout to let the navigator refreshing the info.

I have : (pesudocode)

```
main() 
{ load_data();
  analize_data();
}

load_data () {
settimeout(read1 , 300);
settimeout(read2 , 300);
settimeout(read3 , 300);
}
```

My problem and ignorance :
- Is every setttimeoput wait until previous code "timed" have finished ? Can I trust in that I'll have a start-end flow control betwen settimeouts ? (or not ?)
- Have I to define a settimeout for 'analize_data'. if not I enter on the function and I have an error because I have not data read... and I have error of undefined data.
- Have I to define a global strategy for settimeout flow ? (that is, are settimetouts critical for my flow ?  )  If I have 10 functions calls have I to define 10 settimeouts ?

I would be very happy to find something really similar to "do_pending_events" , "dojavascript_events" or "do_DOM_events".

I know this is a very know problem but I keep on without any clear and easy solution , 
My database access mode is local (so I don't need AJAX neither nothing similar)

Any help or link would be appreciated.

Comment: every setTimeout will not wait for the other to finish. setTimeout says "execute the given function in xxx time and continue your current worflow" so all your functions in the setTimeouts will be executed at the same time if they all have the same delay and are declared at the same moment

Answer (score 0):

Your timeouts will all fire at almost the same time - ie. the second  will not wait for the first to finish.
What you do with load_data() function is you set three timeouts, all three scheduled in 300ms, and then return.
Then in about 300ms, read1, read2, and read3 will be called - each with its own scope.

You could do this by using flow.js (https://github.com/willconant/flow-js)

Or on your own.

- call read1, set scope to "this" of load_data()
- have read1 emit "done1" at its end
- have load_data() listen to 'done1' and fire read2 when the event is caught.

You can modify this logic to include as many steps as you want.

Comment: Thank zla. If you have time, can please give me some ideas on emit  and listen ? Thanks again .